# Did word "beavis" mean anything before Beavis&Butthead series were aired?

Tags: meaning, etymology, slang, offensive-language, urban-legends

In other words,why Mike Judge named one of characters "Beavis"? Was there also some slang meaning or word play behind it as in "Butthead"?

Comment: A quick look in [SheKnows.com](http://www.sheknows.com/baby-names/name/beavis) (or in other references) turns up the fact that 'Beavis' is from the old French name 'Beauvais' meaning 'fair [of] face'. [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/Bevis) claims the French town of Beauvais as an intermediate step, with Bevis being the more frequent modern variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a kid in Mike Judge's neighborhood when he was growing up named Bobby Beavis, according to him in [this interview](http://www.inthe80s.com/july1995/animate/beavis.html).  A [Google search of pre-1993 books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22beavis%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1935,cd_max:1993&lr=lang_en) will show many examples of people with that name. There was also a kid who called himself "Iron-Butt", and one of the other kids called him "Butt-Head".

Comment: Wikipedia has a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bevis) of notable people called Bevis, Beavis, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered "beavis" used as a pejorative in the book "Floaters" by Joseph Wambaugh. On page 146 in the first edition of the 1996 hardback, which is the beginning of Chapter 9, it starts with: "On Easter Sunday they were out there on the water: every sailing-stupid and Jet Ski doofus. Every ski-boat beavis and fishing dweeb." Yes, it does say 'sailing-stupid', which is used throughout the book. So it would appear that beavis was used as an insult.

Comment: *Floaters" by Joseph Wambaugh. On page 146 in the first edition of the 1996 hardback*, Beavis and Butt-Head ran for seven seasons from March 8, **1993**.